# OpenCL can not query a platform on android device

Tags: android, opencl

Im using the Qualcomm OpenCL to optimize native C++ code in my android application. The linking in `CMakeLists.txt` is handled as follows:

```
add_library(opencl-lib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties( opencl-lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libOpenCL.so)
target_link_libraries( demo opencl-lib )
```

My reproducible example:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include "opencl-sdk/inc/CL/cl.h"
#include "opencl-sdk/inc/CL/opencl.h"

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_demo_MainActivity_getInt( JNIEnv* env, jobject /* this */) {
    cl_int err = 0;
    cl_uint num_platforms = 0;
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &num_platforms);
    return 0;
}
```

The application crashes immediately after running it. I receive the following message in the Logcat: `libc, com.example.<app_name>, A  Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT), fault addr 0x726e76a004 in tid 29952 (om.example.demo), pid 29952 (om.example.<app_name>)`. It seems like OpenCL is not able to query a device at all. When I comment everything in `Java_com_example_demo_MainActivity_getInt()`, I get a lot of type `DEBUG` logs, including `/data/app/~~6MgdG5XHBNcZSiF0nvJtPg==/com.example.demo-ZvGN17inQLVfZzeCRpFjJA==/base.apk!libOpenCL.so (clGetPlatformIDs+72) (BuildId: 4252b0a3fc7297cc93dfa7a31c208d1f)` . Are there any work-arounds to this issue?